# typescript extends class along with implement interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, interface, extends

I am trying to extend a third party library class mongooseJs so that I can have some custom functionality in there. I have done this in the past with Javascript, like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
class CustomMongoose extends mongoose.Mongoose {
    myCustomMethod() {
        console.log('this is my custom method');
    }
}

const a = new CustomMongoose();
a.model("test"); //This method does get called on parent correctly (code wouldn't work until connection is setup but you get the point)
```

However when I try to do similar thing in typescript, as below, it gives me an error

```
Type 'CustomMongoose' is missing the following properties from type 'CustomMongooseBase': pluralize, connect, createConnection, disconnect, and 39 more.
```

for this code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
import { Schema, Model, Document, Mongoose } from "mongoose";

interface CustomMongooseBase extends Mongoose {
  myCustomMethod(): void;
}

class CustomMongoose extends mongoose.Mongoose implements CustomMongooseBase {
    myCustomMethod(): void {
        console.log('this is my custom method');
    }
}

//this is what I would expect to work, if this compiles fine
// const a = new CustomMongoose();
// a.myCustomMethods(); // should work
// a.model("modelName") //should also work, though this is from the base
```

What I am trying to do is that providing my own interface `CustomMongooseBase`, which in turn extends the `Mongoose` interface. I want the caller of my new class `CustomMongoose` to have my new functionality and everything else as pass through. So in the concrete implementation, I have extended `mongoose.Mongoose` which has implementation of all the methods `Mongoose` interface requires, and my custom class has implementation of new method `myCustomMethod` that my own interface requires, so this should be working, but it's not.

What I am doing wrong here? (New to typescript so trying to get my head around)

==== Slightly different variation with different error ====

```
import { Mongoose } from "mongoose";

export interface CustomMongooseBase extends Mongoose //extending at the interface level so that consumers have the full signature of mine as well as parent interface
{ 
  myCustomMethod(): void;
}

class CustomMongoose extends Mongoose implements CustomMongooseBase {
  myCustomMethod(): void {
    console.log("this is my custom method");
  }
}

//this is what I would expect to work, if this compiles fine
// const a = new CustomMongoose();
// a.myCustomMethods(); // should work
// a.model("modelName") //should also work, though this is from the base
```

and here is a different error now

```
Non-abstract class 'CustomMongoose' does not implement inherited abstract member 'ConnectionBase' from class 'typeof import("mongoose")'.ts(2515)
```

These are my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.36",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.3"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, thank you for your suggestion. Yes, in my actual code, that's how I had it.. Let me correct in the question as well.

Comment: Your question has `const mongoose = require("mongoose");` immediately followed by `import { Schema, Model, Document, Mongoose } from "mongoose";` That's really, really odd. Normally you use *either* CommonJS (`require`) **or** ESM (`import`). You don't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that

1. You have both `const mongoose = require("mongoose");` and `import { Schema, Model, Document, Mongoose } from "mongoose";`. That's really, really odd. Normally you use *either* CommonJS (`require`) **or** ESM (`import`). You don't mix them.

   And,
2. You're using `Mongoose` on `interface CustomMongooseBase extends Mongoose` but you're using `mongoose.Mongoose` on `class CustomMongoose extends mongoose.Mongoose implements CustomMongooseBase`. I suspect `mongoose.Mongoose` isn't resolving to the same type.

I'd fix it by using just one form of module import, and being consistent about naming:

```
import { Schema, Model, Document, Mongoose } from "mongoose";

interface CustomMongooseBase extends Mongoose {
  myCustomMethod(): void;
}

class CustomMongoose extends Mongoose implements CustomMongooseBase {
    myCustomMethod(): void {
        console.log('this is my custom method');
    }
}
```

That said, there's no reason that `CustomMongooseBase` needs to extend `Mongoose`, you could just remove that bit:

```
interface CustomMongooseBase {
  myCustomMethod(): void;
}

class CustomMongoose extends Mongoose implements CustomMongooseBase {
    myCustomMethod(): void {
        console.log('this is my custom method');
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I do see 1st point as a problem i.e. import and require. However I can't get this to work without that in this very specific situation. If I only do import, then it refers to the @types rather than the actual MongooseJS implementation, thereby not giving me the concrete class to pass on the functionality to. As I said I am trying to add some function while leaving rest concrete implementation to mongooseJS. The concrete class from the library is `mongoose.Mongoose`, if you refer to my javascript example that works.

Comment: And also for the second point, the reason I implemented base, is that then I expect users of my interface to get all the methods accessible to them as a type.

Comment: @SubhashDike - Combining `require` and `import` is just not going to work. You'll need to figure out and fix whatever problem you're having just using `import`. I suspect that will solve the problem, but if it doesn't it sounds like there's a problem with your package imports. Normally, when you have a package and also type information for it, that type information is associated with the package's exports. You don't import the implementation and the type information separately. You just import the implementation.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, i.e. removing both require and import, and using only import it still doesn't work. I think the problem very well be limited to this particular library. In my package.json I have both `@types/mongoose `and `mongoose`, and I think the problem is that when I import it refers to only `@types/mongoose`, and I want to extend a class which is concrete implementation from `mongoose` package rather than from `@types`, but it's only pulling abstract class from `@types`, there by giving errors. See the updated question for updated sample

Comment: @SubhashDike - I'm sure Mongoose's type information is defined correctly. I suggest completely removing `mongoose` and `@types/mongoose` from `package.json`, adding `mongoose` back, and then adding `@types/mongoose` back. When doing the latter, remember `--save-dev` (not `--save` and not wihtout either, which is the same as `--save`): `npm i @types/mongoose --save-dev`

Comment: That didn't make any difference. Further reading the docs, this one - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules suggests that the typescript system does load @types/ modules first, and in that case it's not going to load the concrete implementation. If possible for you can we chat here - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221111/typescript

Comment: @SubhashDike - My experience with other libraries with `@types/` modules is that that just isn't the case. You get implementations when they're there, interfaces when they aren't. I've used something like a dozen. I'm sorry you're running into one, but I really think it's your setup, not Mongoose or TypeScript. That's where I would focus my attention if I were you.